# can't upload image file in server

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']))
{

    $filename = "";

    echo $_POST['count'];

    for ($u = - 1;$u < $_POST['count'];$u++)
    {

        $filename = "S0" . (7 + $u) . $_POST['thingno'] . ".jpg";

    }

    // file name
    

    // Location
    $location = '../assets/' . $filename;

    echo $location;

    // file extension
    $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);

    // Valid extensions
    $valid_ext = array(
        "pdf",
        "doc",
        "docx",
        "jpg",
        "png",
        "jpeg"
    );

    $response = 0;

    if (in_array($file_extension, $valid_ext))
    {

        echo "in if";

        // Upload file
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location))
        {

            $response = 1;

        }

    }

    echo $response;

    exit;

}

else

{

    echo "return";

}

?>
```

this is my javascript, html file

```
function uploadFile() {

    

                var filesaa = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb');

                //    var filesaa = document.getElementById("compress-img").src;

                // alert(filesaa);

                

    

                if (filesaa.length > 0) {

                    for (var k = 0; k < filesaa.length; k++) {

                    // alert(filesaa[k].src);

                

                        // console.log(filesaa[k]);

                        var formData = new FormData();

                        formData.append("base64",filesaa[k]);

                        formData.append("count", k);

                        formData.append("thingno", '<?php echo $_GET['value'] ?>');

    

    

                        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    

                        // Set POST method and ajax file path

                        xhttp.open("POST", "fileupload.php", true);

    

                        // call on request changes state

                        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    

                                var response = this.responseText;

                                console.log(response);

                                if (response == 1) {

                                    alert("Upload successfully.");

                                } else {

                                    alert("File not uploaded.");

                                }

                            }

                        };

  

                        // Send request with data

                        xhttp.send(formData);

                    }

                } else {

                    alert("Please select a file");

                }

            }
```

Comment: Please share more details to understand your problem like what error you getting? where it failed?

Comment: You never check `$_FILES['file']['error']`. You do check if `move_uploaded_file()` succeeds (kind of) but it's unclear what you do with that information.